# Sum durations if they meet a criteria? (Google sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to create a dynamic dashboard for staff to track the total amount of time they've worked for our program. They fill out a form with start/end time and denote if it's work that's eligible for our program to pay them for it. I'm building a dashboard where they can see how many extended hours they've racked up over the course of the school year because we have limits on how many hours they can earn.

I'm including an editable
[copy of my spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13bJkFEK4XMMujuKo8m2rh6ANjjvZUTp1c0mCp_9qbv4/edit?usp=sharing) to show what I've got so far... I'd like to add up any durations in column E that have a "Yes" in Column F (which is all of them at the moment) and have that sum sit in cell C5. But all I can get it to do is sum up to zero, and I can visibly see that it should be more than zero. I've tried changing the format of the cell(s) too, but it's still zero.

Any help or ideas are greatly appreciated! And I'm always trying to learn and improve, so if you know how to do this and don't mind explaining to me how the solution works, I'd also really appreciate that so that I can keep getting better at Sheets. :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *But all I can get it to do is sum up to zero,* How are you summing?

Comment: So I'm realizing I need that column in the Data sheet to perform dual-functions, which is maybe the problem? I need it to be converted to text like that to display in a comprehensible way to people using the dashboard, so the TEXT() needs to stay. But I see now (thanks basic!) that it won't sum if I have it converted that way. Anyone have any thoughts on how to have it calculate the difference using the start and end times of eligible entries and then sum those eligible entries, all within one formula in cell C5 in the "Dashboard" sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Played around with it enough that I got it finally!

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(if(C8:C="Yes",E8:E-D8:D,0)))
```

Thanks for helping me troubleshoot and think it through!

Answer (score 2):

This is because the numbers in column `J` (in `Data` sheet) are stored as text. Either enter them instantly as numbers or use the helper column where they are converted by the formula e.g. `=VALUE(J1)`

[image]

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help. I have some questions... What does "enter them instantly as numbers" mean? Type them instead of calculating the difference? This is a template for other sheets, so manually typing them in isn't an option. Plus, if I set the number format as "Duration" (in both sheets), shouldn't that store them as numbers?

I'm just not understanding what you mean... I'm sorry!

Comment: In your spreadsheet I couldn't understand how you got the duration values. That's why I wrote - if you enter them, then write them as numbers, formatting the column accordingly in advance. If it's the result of a formula, then it should have been a number, but somewhere it's incorrectly converted to text. In any case, you can solve this problem with the helper column.

Comment: And, no - formatting value doesn't convert it to number.

Comment: I was originally pulling the data in with a query/importrange combo from another sheet into the "Data" sheet, but with making this copy, I had to censor/alter the names and emails so I "broke" the connection and just pasted in the values. I altered this copy so that the length/duration is being calculated instead, and now the formula you wrote is summing to zero again.

But you're saying to have it calculate the difference and sum it all at once in cell C5 in the "Dashboard" sheet, using the start and end times, instead of using the length values (col E)?

Comment: To calculate duration you use formula ```=ARRAYFORMULA(text(I7:I-H7:H,"hh:mm"))```? ```TEXT``` function returns string. In this case you should avoid using it, just subtract values and then format column as you need.

Comment: So I'm realizing I need that column in the Data sheet to perform dual-functions, which is maybe the problem? I need it to be converted to text like that to display in a comprehensible way to people using the dashboard, so the TEXT() needs to stay. But I see now (thanks basic!) that it won't sum if I have it converted that way. Anyone have any thoughts on how to have it calculate the difference using the start and end times of eligible entries and then sum those eligible entries, all within one formula in cell C5 in the "Dashboard" sheet?